# How to insert REGEX line breaks in Validation Rule

Tags: validation-rule, validation, regular-expressions

The Validation Rule listed below is supposed to fire if the below criteria is not met:

For Sales Orders, enter between 6-8 digits
OR
For Delivery IDs, enter 10 digits.
Users may enter multiple values separated by a comma and/or a return.

The Validation Rule works unless line breaks are introduced. We have been struggling with adding REGEX line breaks so that the Validation Rule still works when Sales Orders or Delivery IDs are added with line breaks instead of commas.

```
AND(
NOT(REGEX(Sales_Order__c, "^0*\\d{6,8}((, ?\\d{6,8})?){0,}$")), 
NOT(ISBLANK(Sales_Order__c))
)
||
AND(
NOT(REGEX(Delivery_Number__c, "^0*\\d{10}((, ?\\d{10})?){0,}$")),
NOT(ISBLANK(Delivery_Number__c))
)
```

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: A couple of points. First of all, what isn't actually working with the regex? Are you getting an error thrown or is it just not picking this up? Secondly (and this is more pedantic than something required for this), given you have an or statement between the two distinct conditions you're checking is there a reason this is a single Validation Rule and not two?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @CallumMacErlich.


So, here's the issue. The Validation Rule works as expected as long as there are no line breaks for the Sales Orders entered.  


For example, when Sales Order is a single line of "123456" the Validation Rule does not fire as expected. But when Sales Order has two separate lines the Validation Rule fires even though I don't want it to. The problem is  I don't know how to include line breaks in my Validation Rule formula.


EXAMPLE Sales Order:
123456
123456

Don't want the Validation Rule to fire but it does.

Comment: No valid reason for why it's not two Validation Rules. Even even I break them up into two different Validation Rules I'm not sure how to add REGEX line breaks to allow Sales Order to include values on two or more lines (with line breaks). Sorry having issues with formatting my replies.

Comment: why not use SUBSTITUTE and replace all line breaks with something like `;` - does that make your regex any easier to compose?

Comment: I've stumbled over this stack Exchange. Don't know anything about SalesForce, but looked up that the regex flavour is supposedly Java? Therefor, have a look at [this](https://regex101.com/r/tVlrfu/1)